# Modify ServletRequest using Filter in a Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlet-filters

There are a few artiles on this, but their solutions do not solve my question.
I have a GET request which looks something like this:
`localhost:8080/rest/users/search?name=john&age=20&count=20`

My requirement is whenever a request contains "count" query parameter, I want to check if the value is not more than 10. If it is more than 10, then replace the query parameter to "count=10"

To solve this, I tried using `javax.servlet.Filter` & `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper` but I am not able to replace the original value from the request.

This is what my WebFilter looks like:

```
@Component
public class WebFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
        logger.debug("Initiating WebFilter >> ");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

            final HttpServletRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new HttpServletRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request);
            if (requestWrapper.getParameterValues("count") != null) {
                String[] count = requestWrapper.getParameterValues("price");

                for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(count[i]) > 10) {
                        count[i] = "10";
                    }
                }
                requestWrapper.setAttribute("count", count);
            }

            System.out.println("count: " + requestWrapper.getParameter("count"));

            // Goes to default servlet
            chain.doFilter(requestWrapper, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        logger.debug("Destroying WebFilter >> ");
    }
}
```

I saw in other post that just by doing `requestWrapper.setAttribute("count", count);` will add the new value to the responseWrapper. But I get the original value all the times.

Comment: 1) you dont need wrapper since you are no extending it - thus its pointless. 2) Its possible that different filter in chain is modyfing it 3) Your filter might be in wrong place in chain (kind of related to 2)

Comment: 4) set attribute does not modify query params - it just adds given attribute to a map that can be read by other components from the same request object - it is a kind of data exchange map.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set query parameter - its immutable from API point of view. What you have to do is to extend request wrapper and override getParameter() method to return value you want to be returned when given query name is provided. So something like this (knee programing in notepad)

```
class YourWrapper{
  ...ctors etc
   @Override
   public String[] getParamter(String name){
         if(name.equals("count"){
             String[] original super.getParameter(name); // get original values, process it and 
             return ...// either original val or String.valueOf(10);
          }
         return super.getParameter(name);
    }
```

}

Than you wrap your request and pass along the filter chain

```
chain.doFilter(new YourWrapper(request),response);
```

So its all about interception.